# Email link opening data URI to download file

Tags: html, html-email, data-uri

I'm using emailJS and passing some HTML in so I can create what the email content is from my javascript code. I'm trying to make an anchor link where the user can click it and it will open a data url which will download a csv file.

`<a href="${csvDownloadURL}" download="shoppr-export.csv">`

This is what I'm writing in the HTML, and the variable 'csvDownloadURL' is like this:

`data:application/octet-stream,Fruit%20%26%20Veg%7CFront%20Shelves`

*(just an example, it's actually a much longer csv string separated by a pipe character.)*

When this is on the website, it works fine when clicked, but when you click it from an email then on Mac Mail it will show the MacOS popup asking which application you want to open this file in, and on iPhone Mail it doesn't do anything when you tap the link.

I've tried looking online to see if this kind of URL is something that can't be used in emails, or if there is some additional parameter that you need to tell it to open in a browser, because if you take the url from the email and directly paste it into a browser it will download the file without issue.

Would appreciate any guidance to try and make this work! Thanks